Find login user in User model laravel
I want to get the authenticated user in the User model in the best method and less query.
I try this (it's work but i want less query for database), has Laravel provided us with a better way?
$userID = Auth::user()->id;
$user = User::find($userID);


@CBroe I know this but i want to access to User model ...

Well, the result of Auth::user() is the User model - at least with the basic installation. The ´UserProvider´ provides you with the the model configured in config/auth.php for your guard configuration.
